# Feminine equivalent of "priapic"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

For a male, if you are enumerating your sexual conquests, you might refer to it as your *priapic conquests*:

> The pirates joined on deck and exchanged stories on their own priapic conquests.

Is there a lesbian equivalent of this phrase? Something like:

> The lesbians joked about their "priapic conquests" (i.e., all the women they had slept with) while they were sizing up their next opponent.

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153668/what-is-the-adjective-corresponding-to-venus

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to keep it simple and say *sexual conquests.*

This terminology while not as flowery conveys the exact sense of what you mean.

If you really want it to be lesbian and flowery, then try *sapphic*.

Sapphic refers to the Greek poet [Sappho](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sappho) born on the isle of Lesbos.  The term has come to be synonymous with lesbian sexuality.

I think the *priapic* concept is lost when describing the sexuality of women because of the lack of necessity for an erection for sexual activity.

Comment: Not fond of the digressions in the answer, but +1 for _sapphic._

Comment: @BraddSzonye the digression is necessary to make sure we're not comparing apples to oranges.  But, I'll delete the last bit. Too controversial.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, while women may not require an erection the same way that males do, sexual activity still generally requires arousal. Or ouch.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Well, I'm neither a virgin nor an animal!!!!  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I was also going to recommend *aphroditic*, since the origin of *priapic* is from *Priapus*, a [Greek fertility god](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priapus).

Also, because *priapic* is essentially synonymous with *phallic* you could substitute with, the female equivalent, "yonic".

Answer (score 2):

There are some possibilities, but none fit extremely well. The reason is historical: [Priapus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priapus) was a minor Greek god of various things, among them male virility; he was "marked by his absurdly oversized, permanent erection". There is no real female equivalent of Priapus because society was more patriarchal, and vivid female sexuality was not seen as virtuous.

The closest female equivalents to Priapus would be Aphrodite or Venus, but neither of them really invoke the connotation you want. Direct references to genitalia (e.g. "labial conquests" as another answer put it) seem too vulgar and awkward to really work well in prose.

For your purposes, I would suggest *nymphic*, which has strong connotations of sexual virility and promiscuity among females.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you ask for a feminine equivalent in your question, but the original phrase does not necessarily (and in the case of pirates, is unlikely to) refer to same-sex-encounters.

Now, the word *priapic* originates from the name of a minor Greek god, who was know for his, let's say, outspokenly present and continuously active masculinity.

One option would be to find a female equivalent, and the one that comes to mind is Aphrodite or Venus.

The adjective for Venus is venereal, but I doubt *venereal* conquests would have any positive ring to it, because of the common association with venereal diseases. You could try ***aphroditic* conquests**, maybe.

Alternatively, you could look for something more physical, as *priapic* is a direct hint at the erect penis. Although some parts of a female body may become erect, I am not sure that those erections evoke the same image or impact as the priapic one.
However, you could throw in (an allusion to) some other parts of the female anatomy.

*Labial* conquest comes to mind, but it might mean that they relatively innocently kissed someone.
*Vulvic* conquests would be an option I guess, descriptive of the kind of conquest.
You could play around with adjectives based on less formal nouns for the female anatomy, but I will leave that up to your own imagination and what you see fit for the context.

Comment: There is no "common association with veneric diseases", as there are no veneric diseases. I think you're referring to _venereal_ diseases.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Good point :)

Comment: Alternatives to _venereal_: _Venusian_ is a more common adjective for Venus, at least in my experience. _Venerean_ seems more in line with Latin principles. And then there's _Cytherean_, created by Astronomers and since fallen into disuse.